# Appending nested svg elements with D3js data binding?

Tags: d3.js, svg, data-binding, append

I am trying, usin D3js data bindins, to append rectangles as children of a transformed svg element.
My rectangles actually get appended but they are appended to the `html` element (I mean the root element of the html document) and not as children of the `g` element I thought would be their parent node.
How can I them appended as children nodes of the `g` element?

```
//var svgTranslate = (sgv:g with some transform applied)

var myclassSelection = svgTranslate.select('rect.myclass');
var myclassBinding = myclassSelection.data(data);
var myclassBindingEnter = myclassBinding.enter();

myclassBindingEnter
.append('rect')
    .attr('class','myclass')
    .attr('x', function(d) { return d[0]; })
    .attr('y', 0)
    .attr('width', function(d) { return d[1]; })
    .attr('height', 25)
;
```

Comment: Can you post your code showing how you create the svgTranslate object please?

Comment: You need `.selectAll()` instead of `.select()`.

Comment: Thank you. .selectAll() solved it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As replied by Lars Kotthoff in the comments, I had to ue `.selectAll()` instead of `.select()`